# Simple Java Web Service client over HTTPS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, https

I am connecting to a simple XML over HTTPS web service and getting a security exception. My question is whether you think the cause of this is the cert on the web server, so I should talk to the server admin or if my client code should be handling this. I would love to hear if anyone has encountered and solved this issue. Is the solution found on client side or server side? Below is the exception.

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Violated path length constraints
at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.checkBasicConstraints(SimpleValidator.java:243)
at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.checkExtensions(SimpleValidator.java:158)
at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:143)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:202)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(DashoA12275)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(DashoA12275)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth testing the client side first with [openssl](http://swamp.homelinux.net/blog/index.php/2008/05/15/openssl-s_client/)

```
openssl s_client -connect yourserver.com:443
```

Check out the man page for further options.

What happens when you access it with a web browser? Firefox should provide you quite some information on the server cert.

While it does not seem like you after client cert authentication [this examples](http://vafer.org/blog/20061010073725) does show you how to use a custom SSLSocketFactory. It can also be set statically - if you don't have access to the connection.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, I would guess that it's a problem with the server's certificate (the trace originates from "checkServerTrusted" calls).  You might want to try connecting to the URL with a web browser such as Firefox to see if you get an SSL error with more details.